# How to move cursor in expression insert mode mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to create a plugin for inserting things like closing quotes, brackets, parenthesis and xml tags. I know about delimitMate, auto-pairs and others, but I'm not satisfied with them.

DelimitMate is kind hard to configure and nice features like `<CR>` expansion doesn't work by default.

auto-pairs doesn't work with Python in things like `b''`

To insert a closing tag you have to install another plugin and it doesn't work very well (It's been a long time since I tried).

Everyone is telling that inserting a pairs automatically is surprisingly hard, but I thought about it for a while and it doesn't seem that hard at all.

Basically you need to map every character that can trigger insertion to a function that would search a list of user defined regexes for a pair of regexes that would match text before and after the cursor. If match is found is passed to a function that would return the actual text to insert.

This way for example inserting closing tags, python's `""""""`, `f''`is trivial.
Here's a proof of concept code

```
fu! RetMatch(matched)
    return '></' . join(reverse(split(a:matched, '.\zs')), '') . '>'
endfu

fu! SmartPair()
    " let pairs = {'"': [['""', '"""'], ['[bfr]\?', '"']]}
    let pairs = {'>': [['[^<]\+\ze<', function('RetMatch')]]}
    let reversed_line = join(reverse(split(getline('.')[:col('.')], '.\zs')), '')
    let longest_match_len = -1
    let longest_match = ''
    let Longest_substitution = ''
    for [pattern, Substitution] in pairs['>']
        let [matched, mstart, mend] = matchstrpos(reversed_line, pattern)
        if mstart == 0 && mend - mstart >= longest_match_len
            let longest_match_len = mend - mstart
            let longest_match = matched
            let Longest_substitution = Substitution
        endif
    endfor
    let substitution_type = type(Longest_substitution)
    if longest_match_len >= 0
        if substitution_type == 1
            return '"' . longest_substitution
        elseif substitution_type == 2
            return Longest_substitution(longest_match)
        endif
    else
        return '"'
    endif
endfu

inoremap <expr> " SmartPair()
inoremap <expr> > SmartPair()
```

Notice how the same approarch makes inserting so called space expansion easy, you just need to define a mapping for space, the regexes pair would be something like `'('` to match before the cursor, and `')'` to match after and a function that would return resulting text would return two spaces.

I think this also can be achieved by using `InsertCharPre`...

Comment: so you have described your approach quite well. I am missing, what exactly your problem is.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  didn't new how to move cursor in `<expr>` mapping. I've done that by copying approach of auto-pairs plugin. The use `<silent> <C-R>=...` and then append `<Left>`. It's working now, but maybe there's a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `<expr>` mappings, you are not allowed to move the cursor (or rather the position of the cursor will be restored afterwards) as it is written in the [help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#:map-expression).

However what you can do is return the keychars which would move the cursor, e.g. in your expr do something like this:

```
nmap <expr> , Foobar()
function Foobar()
  "... do some magic
  let result="..."
  return "\<left>\<left>".result
endfunction
```

So don't move the cursor directly, but make the result of your expression move the cursor.

Comment: Strangly It didn't worked when I tried it the first time, but worked with `<C-R>=`, but now it's working either way. What's the difference between mapping with  and `<expr>`